# CSS element style set properly onMouseDown, why undesired reset onMouseUp?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some head text/javascript:

```
function Show() {
    document.getElementById("Popup").style["display"] = "block";
}
function Hide() {
    document.getElementById("Popup").style["display"] = "none";
}
```

In the body I do:

```
<a href="" onMouseDown="Show()" onMouseUp=""><img src="blah.jpg"/></a>
...
<a href="" onClick="Hide()">X</a>
```

My CSS has:

```
#Popup {
    display:none;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);   
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 160%;
    ...
}
```

When I click on blah.jpg the Popup appears as expected .. but as soon as I mouseUp the popup disappears.  I want it to stay present until the "X" (in the second anchor tag) is clicked.  In the first anchor tag I tried onMouseUp="", but no happy.  Works same way in Chrome and Firefox.

What to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `href` attribute to "#" on your links. An empty href attribute will reload the current page, which is what you're seeing. It's not that the popup is going away, it's that you're refreshing the page when you mouse up!

e.g.

```
<a href="#" onMouseDown="Show()" onMouseUp=""><img src="blah.jpg"/></a>
...
<a href="#" onClick="Hide()">X</a>
```

Alternatively, you could set "return false;" on your `onmousedown` event. That stops the link performing the redirect by telling it to:

1. Prevent the default behavior, and
2. not bubble the event up to parent elements (a *click* on a link will also perform a click on the links parent elements, and so on).

e.g.

```
<a href="" onclick="Show(); return false;"><img src="blah.jpg"/></a>
...
<a href="" onClick="Hide()">X</a>
```